# Facebook JS API - Post Custom Image Along with Link NO Meta Tag Reliance

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This seems way harder than it should be for what I would think would be a common action (I don't personally do Facebook, so maybe it isn't), but I'm basically just trying to offer the user a dialog to post something to their wall where I pick the image being shared and include a custom description for them.

**The Goal**

Users are generating their own content on the page, drag-and-dropping items around, and when they're finished I'll generate an image of their canvas and upload it to our server. What I then need them to be able to do is click a "Share mine on Facebook!" button that would, ideally, give a dialog that pipes in that image I just generated on the server along with a description of "Hey look what I made at yada yada yada".

**What I've Tried**

I have gone from using the simpler feed/dialog `FB.ui` calls to a full-blown API integration of requesting `publish_actions` permissions and authenticating them with the web app to automatically post on their behalf. Through all of these, I can't include a link and also specify their custom image. It keeps pulling from the OG meta tag/scraped image for the post, and I see no parameters to pass that would allow me to specify an image.

It looks like I could maybe upload a photo to one of their albums, and then grab it from there and generate the post...but that seems super invasive and requires additional permission requests, which is stupid.

Has anyone come up with a way to hack around this terrible reliance on static meta tags for generating post content? Or am I just not understanding this and it's actually a great thing?

Any help is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: Just generate unique URLs and have people share them.

Comment: If I were just sharing the image that would be alright, but they'll need to be able to interact with things on the page once someone clicks through the Facebook post to it. I guess I could just have a redirect on the unique image pages.

Comment: If I see a cool photo and I click on it I would expect to be taken to it. Not somewhere else

Comment: _“Or am I just not understanding this and it's actually a great thing?”_ – yes, it is a great thing, because it makes it harder for fake news creators to link to articles by respected, trusted media outlets while faking the title/description/thumbnail to make it appear to the casual observer that the article was saying something completely different, resp. the opposite of what it actually does.